# Scraping react component with selenium (python)

Tags: python, reactjs, selenium, web-scraping

I want to **scrape** some data from a uber account.
So I need to identify myself. That work perfectly fine when I use Selenium without the headless option, but with this option on, it seems I can't retrieve the password input.
When I looked for the source code of the page (https://auth.uber.com/login/), I see an input for the email but not for the password. But for some odd reasons I can see the password input in the javascript console (but copy the css selector or whatever doesn't work with the headless option on).That means this input is created by js but why I can't catch this input with the headless option on ? (I've tried to put some time.sleep(x) but that didn't work)

EDIT:
my code so far

```py
    mail=driver.find_element_by_id('useridInput')
    mail.send_keys(Uber.login_data['mail'])
    driver.find_element_by_tag_name('button').click()
    time.sleep(5)
    password=driver.find_element_by_name('password')
    password.send_keys(Uber.login_data['password'])
    driver.find_element_by_tag_name('button').click()
    time.sleep(5)
```

I don't think my code is the problem, I've also tried to increment the time.sleep(x)
The problem is that I'm always getting the same error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element:         Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"  [name="password"]"}
```

But in the js console

```
<input type="password" class="text-input " name="password" id="password" value="" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" aria-describedby="error-caption input-title input-label" style="box-shadow: white 0px 0px 0px 30px inset; background-image: url(&quot;data:image/png;base64,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&quot;); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-attachment: scroll; background-size: 16px 18px; background-position: 98% 50%; cursor: auto;" autocomplete="off">
```

Just before this input, I have

```
<!-- react-empty: 353 -->
```

I don't know what it means, if that can explain why I can't select the input.
In the source code, I've the input for the email but not for the password.

There is no iframe by the way

I have a another problem I didn't have yesterday. When I enter my email, looks fine but just after I have this pop-up which appear:
[image]

Which means whatever the headless option is on or not but I cannot **scrape** my data. I Don't know if there is a tip to handle that with selenium

Comment: you could save source code when you run headless and check what you get in HTML. You should also check if this element is not in `<iframe>` because it would need `driver.switch_to.frame()`

Comment: Update the question with your code trials and relevant HTML